# How can I use Spring Data for Redis serializers?

Tags: spring, redis, spring-data, spring-data-redis

I'm studing Spring Data for Redis, but until now I have not found any example about how to use the serializers supported by this project?

I've read the section 4.6 of the reference documentation of the project ( http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-redis/docs/current/reference/html/redis.html#redis:serializer ) but it basically only says that it exists. Nothing more. How can I use this feature?

Comment: @ Kico Lobo - Did you able to solve this without using RedisTemplate and I am not using it at all

Answer (score 2):

Serializers are used in a few places in the codebase, most notably in RedisTemplate to convert the raw bytes stored in Redis as keys/values to your custom data types (and vice versa).  This is mentioned in Section 4.4 of the documentation.

Comment: @ Jennifer Hickey - We're not using RedisTemplate at all to fetch and save data. Its purely CRUD operations. Could you please guide now ?

Answer (score 0):

> In your **spring config**

```
<bean id="stringSerializer" class="org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.StringRedisSerializer"/>

<bean id="redisTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate" 
    p:connection-factory-ref="jedisConnectionFactory">
    <property name="keySerializer" ref="stringSerializer"/>
    <property name="valueSerializer" ref="stringSerializer"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jedisConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory" 
    p:host-name="myhostname" p:port="6379"/>
```

> Or if you want to set it in **Java**

```
// inject the actual template 
      @Autowired
      private RedisTemplate<String, Object> template;
...
...
template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
template.setValueSerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
```